# Docker build troubles with PyFlink container creating

Tags: macos, dockerfile, apache-flink, pyflink

Does somebody have the same issue while building the PyFlink Docker container on Mac m1 machine?
The build fails on Step 4/6 during the pip3 installation process for apache-flink and apache-flink-libraries. Getting all time error about the Include folder should be at '/opt/java/openjdk/include' but doesn't exist. Seems like JDK was not installed in Contaner properly, which is unreal.

Upgrading/installing JDK is not helping. Is it some issue with the container itself?
I don't like to use apache/flink docker image repository as there are only amd64 images and it is Sponsored OSS.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM flink:1.17.1

# Install JDK and essential libraries
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jdk build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libffi-dev lzma liblzma-dev bash

# Install Python 3.10.13
RUN set -ex; \
    wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.13/Python-3.10.13.tgz && \
    tar -xvf Python-3.10.13.tgz && \
    cd Python-3.10.13 && \
    ./configure --without-tests --enable-shared && \
    make -j6 && \
    make install && \
    ldconfig /usr/local/lib && \
    cd .. && rm -f Python-3.10.13.tgz && rm -rf Python-3.10.13 && \
    ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip

# Install Apache Flink
COPY apache-flink*.tar.gz /
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir /apache-flink-libraries*.tar.gz -v
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir /apache-flink*.tar.gz -v

# Download connector libraries
RUN wget -P /opt/flink/lib/ https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/flink/flink-json/1.17.1/flink-json-1.17.1.jar; \
    wget -P /opt/flink/lib/ https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/flink/flink-sql-connector-kafka/1.17.1/flink-sql-connector-kafka-1.17.1.jar; \
    wget -P /opt/flink/lib/ https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/flink/flink-sql-connector-elasticsearch7/3.0.1-1.17/flink-sql-connector-elasticsearch7-3.0.1-1.17.jar;

WORKDIR /opt/flink
```

Error log is below :

```
18.98   WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
19.03   Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
19.03   Getting requirements to build wheel: started
19.03   Running command Getting requirements to build wheel
19.10   Include folder should be at '/opt/java/openjdk/include' but doesn't exist. Please check you've installed the JDK properly.
19.12   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
19.12   
19.12   × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
19.12   │ exit code: 255
19.12   ╰─> See above for output.
19.12   
19.12   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
19.12   full command: /usr/local/bin/python3.10 /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpwujq3uju
19.12   cwd: /tmp/pip-install-71b1sm0q/pemja_2bee4b6bba71423b9a43f21b71487474
19.12   Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
19.12 error: subprocess-exited-with-error
19.12 
19.12 × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
19.12 │ exit code: 255
19.12 ╰─> See above for output.
19.12 
19.12 note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
------
dockerfile:24
--------------------
  22 |     COPY apache-flink*.tar.gz /
  23 |     RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir /apache-flink-libraries*.tar.gz -v
  24 | >>> RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir /apache-flink*.tar.gz -v
  25 |     
  26 |     # Download connector libraries
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip3 install --no-cache-dir /apache-flink*.tar.gz -v" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Comment: just FYI, for Flink 1.17.1 you need `Python 3.10`

Comment: Verify python installation first. If it is installed correctly then try `python -m pip install libraries` and verify if you have JDK 11 ?

Comment: Thank you. I have modified the Dockerfile. See my amended message above but still facing a similar issue with installing Apache Flink dependencies.

Comment: Did you try executing these commands locally first? Were you able to install Flink libraries locally? Also, why don't you unpack the libraries first if there is some problem installing via tar file? Before building up a docker file, I suggest trying locally or spawning up the same docker image and running these commands first.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I tried it all inside of the Docker container and got the same result. I did not install Flink locally.

Comment: Okay also modify your question in order to explain your objective in detail. Give some description about the commands you are trying and what are those commands for.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** Upon further investigation of my own image, I was able to get it to build by

1. Installing `openjdk-11-jdk-headless`
2. Setting `ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-arm64` before my pip install.

Updated Dockerfile

```
FROM flink:1.17.1

# Versions
ENV \
  # Apt-Get
  BUILD_ESSENTIAL_VER=12.9ubuntu3 \
  JDK_VER=11.0.20.1+1-0ubuntu1~22.04 \
  LIBBZ2_DEV_VER=1.0.8-5build1 \
  LIBFFI_DEV_VER=3.4.2-4 \
  LIBSSL_DEV_VER=3.0.2-0ubuntu1.10 \
  ZLIB1G_DEV_VER=1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu9.2 \
  # Python
  PYTHON_VER=3.10.13 \
  # PyFlink
  APACHE_FLINK_VER=1.17.1
  
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-ceuxo", "pipefail"]

RUN apt-get update -y && \
  apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential=${BUILD_ESSENTIAL_VER} \
    openjdk-11-jdk-headless=${JDK_VER} \
    libbz2-dev=${LIBBZ2_DEV_VER} \
    libffi-dev=${LIBFFI_DEV_VER} \
    libssl-dev=${LIBSSL_DEV_VER} \
    zlib1g-dev=${ZLIB1G_DEV_VER} \
  && \
  wget -q "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${PYTHON_VER}/Python-${PYTHON_VER}.tar.xz" && \
  tar -xf "Python-${PYTHON_VER}.tar.xz" && \
  cd "Python-${PYTHON_VER}" && \
  ./configure --enable-optimizations --without-tests --enable-shared && \
  make -j$(nproc) && \
  make install && \
  ldconfig /usr/local/lib && \
  cd .. && \
  rm -rf "Python-${PYTHON_VER}" "Python-${PYTHON_VER}.tar.xz" && \
  ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python && \
  apt-get clean && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Installing OpenJDK again & setting this is required due to a bug with M1 Macs
ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-arm64

RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir apache-flink==${APACHE_FLINK_VER} && \
  pip3 cache purge

USER flink
RUN mkdir /opt/flink/usrlib
COPY python_demo.py /opt/flink/usrlib/python_demo.py
```

---

**Old:** I encountered the same issue under the same circumstances (`17.1`, M1). I assume it's an ARM issue since I was able to build the exact same Dockerfile (below) successfully on an x86 machine.

I replicated the same issue when trying to build [the example pyflink Dockerfile](https://github.com/apache/flink-kubernetes-operator/blob/main/examples/flink-python-example/Dockerfile) as well.

Comment: To be compatible with other architectures as well I created a `setup.sh` script and added the following: `export JAVA_HOME=$(echo /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-*)`. After that I run `pip install apache-flink`